# Does British Columbia legislate for service to be performed 'with reasonable care and skill' + 'within a reasonable time'?

Tags: contract-law, british-columbia

Does B.C. enact any laws like the UK's Consumer Rights Act 2015, sections

##### 49 Service to be performed with reasonable care and skill

> [(1) Every contract to supply a service is to be treated as including a term that the trader must perform the service with reasonable care and skill.](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/49/enacted)

##### 52 Service to be performed within a reasonable time

> [(2) In that case the contract is to be treated as including a term that the trader must perform the service within a reasonable time.](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/52/enacted)

I see nothing similar in the [*Business Practices and Consumer Protection Act*, SBC 2004](https://canlii.ca/t/562bp),
or [*Sale of Goods Act*, RSBC 1996](https://canlii.ca/t/565gm). Did I over look?

I know, B.C. is no longer part of British Empire, and Canadian law differs from UK law. But I am startled if BC fails to protect care, skill, and timeliness, when UK does!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These terms are not implied by legislation in any jurisdiction in Canada, but they are widely recognized as being implied by common law.

There is an "implied term in every contract for services that the person providing the service, whether he be a plumber or a physician, will exercise reasonable care and skill": *De la Giroday v. Brough*, [1997 CanLII 2662 (BC CA), at para 34](https://canlii.ca/t/1dznz#par34).

Completion within a reasonable time is likewise commonly found to be an implied term of a contract: see e.g. *Ring Contracting Ltd. v. Aecon Construction Group Inc.*, [2006 BCCA 304](https://canlii.ca/t/1nn0j).

Comment: Thanks. But how do you know "These terms are not implied by legislation in any jurisdiction in Canada" ? Has some consumer law textbook canvassed every Canadian jurisdiction's consumer protection legislation, and published this conclusion? Or did you peruse every Canadian jurisdiction's consumer protection legislation ? No eye strain ?